# How many subspaces of $\mathbb R^2$ over $\mathbb R$ are there?

Tags: linear-algebra

How many subspaces of $\mathbb R^2$ over $\mathbb R$ are there? Is it finitely many or infinitely many?

Should I consider the case "upto isomorphism"? Then it is finite in number (subspace of dim 0, subspace of dim 1, subspace of dim 2). Otherwise it is infinite.

Which is the correct answer? I am confused.

Comment: Without the phrase "up to isomorphism", there are an infinite number:  there's one line for each real number (and one more), together with the origin and the whole space.

Comment: It sounds like you know the correct answers to both versions of your question.